# Handle Multiple Local Notification in IOS SDK

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uilocalnotification

In my Background method, i scheduled the two notification as follow.

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{
   localNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init]; //Create the localNotification object which is declared in appDelegate.h
    [localNotification setFireDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:[datePicker countDownDuration]]]; //Set the date when the alert will be launched using the date adding the time the user selected on the timer
    [localNotification setAlertAction:@"Launch"]; //The button's text that launches the application and is shown in the alert
    [localNotification setAlertBody:[alertBodyField text]]; //Set the message in the notification from the textField's text
    [localNotification setHasAction: YES]; //Set that pushing the button will launch the application
    [localNotification setApplicationIconBadgeNumber:[[UIApplication sharedApplication] applicationIconBadgeNumber]+1]; //Set the Application Icon Badge Number of the application's icon to the current Application Icon Badge Number plus 1
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotification]; //Schedule the notification with the system
```

//    ********       Notification 2*********

```
localNotification2 = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init]; //Create the localNotification object which is declared in appDelegate.h
        [localNotification2 setFireDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:[datePicker countDownDuration]]]; //Set the date when the alert will be launched using the date adding the time the user selected on the timer
        [localNotification2 setAlertAction:@"Launch"]; //The button's text that launches the application and is shown in the alert
        [localNotification2 setAlertBody:[alertBodyField text]]; //Set the message in the notification from the textField's text
        [localNotification2 setHasAction: YES]; //Set that pushing the button will launch the application
        [localNotification2 setApplicationIconBadgeNumber:[[UIApplication sharedApplication] applicationIconBadgeNumber]+1]; //Set the Application Icon Badge Number of the application's icon to the current Application Icon Badge Number plus 1
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotification2]; //Schedule the notification with the system

}
```

**It works fine for coming the notification.**

**Question**

How can I detect which notification is come in `didreceivenotification method`??
Because I want to do the different task based on the notification came.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the [userInfo Dictionary](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Reference/UILocalNotification_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UILocalNotification/userInfo)

```
localNotification1 = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init]; 
localNotification1.userInfo = @{ "type" : @1 };
...
localNotification2 = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init]; 
localNotification2.userInfo = @{ "type" : @2 };
...
...
```

Answer (score 0):

you can set a `NSDictionary` in `userInfo` property of a `UILocalNotification`

So you can do it this way...

```
localNotification1.userInfo = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"1" forKey:@"NO"];
localNotification1.userInfo = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"2" forKey:@"NO"];
```

and compare the key "NO" in `didReceiveNotification`.